# How do I automatically upload the image I took to a cloud storage like Google Drive or Dropbox

Tags: android, android-camera, dropbox-api, android-file, google-drive-api

I'm a total newbie in Android programming and I was wondering if it's possible for me to automatically upload the image that I took using the camera app that i develop to a cloud storage like the Google Drive or Dropbox.  I am able to get the image saved to an internal SD Card currently.  Here's what I have so far:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_control, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl 
        = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

    Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
    buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, 
                    myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
        }});

}

ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Bitmap bitmapPicture 
            = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);  */

        /*Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

        /*OutputStream imageFileOS;*/


        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

        try 
        {
            /*imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
            imageFileOS.write(arg0);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();

            Toast.makeText(VuzixCamera.this, "Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "nypdImages");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) 
            {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) 
                {
                    Log.d("nypdImages", "Oops! Failed create " + "nypdImages" + " directory");
                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";


            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(path, System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(arg0);
            outStream.close();

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); 

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //VuzixCamera.super.onBackPressed();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
    }};



@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(previewing){
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null){
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little open-ended, but yes. I can only speak to Dropbox, but you can use the Dropbox [Core](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android) or [Sync](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android) API to upload local files, such as photos like this, to a Dropbox account.

Each of those linked pages have links for downloading the relevant SDK, as well as to tutorials that show you how to upload and download files.

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there if you have the file on the SD Card (or just have an InputStream to it).

I can't vouch for Dropbox, but here's an example of connecting to Google Drive and uploading the picture taken. Everything in one place without using any helper methods.

Note: you still need to execute the [integration](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) tutorial of Google Drive.

```
package net.twisterrob.example;

import java.io.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.*;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.*;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.ContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder.DriveFileResult;

/**
 * Upload a single picture taken with the Camera based on some tutorials on Google Drive API:
 * <ul>
 * <li><a href="http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html">take a picture</a>
 * <li><a href="https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth">for connect to work</a>
 * <li><a href="https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file">create the file</a>
 * <li><a href="https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files">upload the file</a>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * Permissions needed:
 * <ul>
 * <li><code>&lt;uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /></code>
 * <li><code>&lt;uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /></code>
 * <li><code>&lt;uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/></code>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * One thing to note with this: for the first connect (sign in/authorization) you need network,
 * but after that everything works without network. 
 */
public class GoogleDriveUpload extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Drive";

    private static final int RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 0;
    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE = RESULT_FIRST_USER + 1;

    private GoogleApiClient mClient;
    private File requestedFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO init UI

        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext()) //
                .addApi(Drive.API) //
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE) //
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this) //
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) //
                .build();
    }

    protected void takePicture() {
        Log.v(TAG, "takePicture");
        requestedFile = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "temp.jpg");
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(requestedFile));
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    protected void upload(final File file) {
        Log.v(TAG, "uploading " + file);
        new FileUploader(mClient) {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(DriveFile result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (result != null) {
                    Log.v(TAG, file + " to " + result.getDriveId());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded to Google Drive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    file.delete();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                finish(); // TODO notify user
            }
        }.execute(file);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v(TAG, "onStart: connecting");
        mClient.connect(); // if it's in onStart the whole activity will be connected
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onStop: disconnecting");
        mClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult: everything ok, connecting");
                    mClient.connect(); // try again with resolved problem
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult: user cancelled?");
                }
                break;
            case TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult: got an image");
                    upload(requestedFile);
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult: error taking picture");
                }
                break;
            default:
                // let super do its thing
                break;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: cannot resolve: " + result);
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: resolving: " + result);
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while trying to resolve " + result, e);
        }
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onConnected: yaay, from here on we can use the Drive API");
        if (requestedFile == null) {
            takePicture(); // TODO call takePicture() from an onClick button event handler
        }
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int reason) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: don't touch Drive API any more");
    }

    private static class FileUploader extends AsyncTask<File, Void, DriveFile> {
        private final GoogleApiClient client;
        private FileUploader(GoogleApiClient client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        @Override
        protected DriveFile doInBackground(File... params) {
            File file = params[0];
            ContentsResult result = Drive.DriveApi.newContents(client).await();
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create contents");
                return null;
            }

            Contents contents = result.getContents();
            try {
                copy(file, contents);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot upload file", ex);
                return null;
            }
            MetadataChangeSet metadata = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder() //
                    .setTitle("picture.jpg") //
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg") //
                    .build();
            DriveFolder root = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(client);
            DriveFileResult createResult = root.createFile(client, metadata, contents).await();
            if (!createResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create file");
                return null;
            }
            return createResult.getDriveFile();
        }

        private static void copy(File source, Contents target) throws IOException {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            try {
                input = new FileInputStream(source);
                output = target.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1014];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            } finally {
                if (input != null) {
                    try {
                        input.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot close input", ex);
                    }
                }
                if (output != null) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot close output", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```